# How to pause gameLoop efficiently

Tags: javascript, html

I am writing a html5 game from scratch.
I need a method in gameEngine which when called pauses the game loop.
Is there a more efficient way of doing this than using setTimeout,setInterval?

```
gameEngine.prototype.start = function () {
    var that = this;
    (function gameLoop() {
        that.loop();
        requestAnimFrame(gameLoop, that.canvctx.canvas);
    })();
}
```

Comment: not in using a self invoking function where you have basicaly no control over , you need a state machine.

Comment: @camus can you please explain a little more i don't really understand what you mean by using state machine.

Comment: State Machine: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite-state_machine.  Basically, you a number of variables to keep track of the current state of things and based on that state decides whether you should issue the next iteration or not.  Imagine you have a single variable called `pause` that before doing the next requestAnimFrame you check it's value and if it's true, it doesn't keep going.

Comment: @jfriend00 but the thing is how to pause it.

Comment: Before calling requestAnimFrame, you check to see if the pause variable is set.  If it is, you don't call requestAnimFrame and thus it is paused.

Comment: @jfriend00 I understand that but when starting it again i will have to continuously check for the pause variable so that when the variable is set i can resume i want to know a better method of doing that.

Comment: @ShubhamSharma - there is no better way.  Every iteration needs to check for the pause variable.  That's how you solve this problem.  What's the big deal, it takes one line of code in one place to check the pause variable on each iteration.